# FB.login not triggering in mobile browsers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile-website, facebook-authentication, mobile-browser

I'm building a mobile web site that directs users through Facebook auth with the following code

```
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '{app_id}', // App ID from the app dashboard
        channelUrl: '{app url}', // Channel file for x-domain comms
        status: true, // Check Facebook Login status
        xfbml: true
    });

    FB.login(function (response) {
    //FB.login contents
    }, {
        scope: '{permissions}'
    });
}
```

This works on desktop browsers but in mobile browsers FB.login doesn't trigger. It seems many people have had this issue. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370550/fb-login-not-firing-for-html5-ios-web-app) Stack Exchange question FB.login cannot be fired inside window.fbAsyncInit and the best way around the issue is to have a button that triggers FB.login once everything is loaded. Can someone authoritative verify that this is my best option before I implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to use `FB.getLoginStatus` instead `FB.login` in `fbAsyncInit` part, and then based on the current status you can sign in user, or use his credentials. Got something like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(auth){
        if(auth.status==='connected'){
            // subscribe to event, and do some magic stuff when status changes
        }
    });

    FB.init({
        appId: fb_config_app_id,        // App ID from the app dashboard
        channelUrl: fb_config_channel,  // Channel file for x-domain comms
        status: true,                   // Check Facebook Login status
        xfbml: true                     // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Load in the user credentials
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // hey - user is already connected !
        } else {
            // login user
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Slavomir, the FB.getLoginStatus function does work in fbAsyncInit as you've asserted, However it should be noted that ultimately a user that is either not logged in or authorized still must go through the FB.Login which (as far as I can tell) is best trigger by a button on a different page.

Comment: Hi @BenPearce - are you sure ? Me example comes from live project, i'm using given example and works for me :)